# How can I get files that differ from older versions on GitLab? (Unique Identifier)

Tags: git, file, gitlab, identifier

I need to know if there is something like an unique identifier for each file on GitLab.

So that we can retrieve an archive that was changed before the next build of our application. SO if there is something new we can re-upload the files on our builder and then deploy the application.

I've only found Path as being this "unique identifier", but if the file has it named changed the file Path is also alterated. So it doesn't work for us.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please edit your question to explain in more details the actions you want to do with git and/or gitlab ? you mention a builder, but the elements you mention around it do not seem to match a regular CI pipeline builder ; can you please explain how your builder works ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps comparing files between two commits can be an option for you. Then you can try using command `git diff --diff-filter=d $COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $COMMIT_SHA --name-only "*.py"`. This will return changed python files between two commits. 
*) You can also omit `--name-only` argument to return all files, and `--diff-filter=d` for showing also deleted files.

Comment: Please, add a brief explanation of meaning of the flags you mentioned. It can really help to not blindly copy-paste the code snippet, but to understand how it works. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, sorry for late feedback. If it is still relevant: `--diff-filter=d` excludes any deleted files from the ones the changed.`--name-only "*.py"` specifies the extension you care in the changed files. When `git diff` command is used without these two flags, it will return changed files including deleted ones, and of any extension.